# Stripe payment with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am creating a system with laravel 7 and I need both subscription service  and one time payment. I am new to stripe. For one time payment I am using stripe charge method and it is working fine. For subscription I am using again charge method. But I have created a cron job which runs every day and check if one month or the selected day is passed cut fee from the customer account. The thing is I am confuse here what if due to any reason the payment is failed I need here to send the email to stripe admin whose account is working and the customer that the payment is failed. But in response of payment charged I cant get status of payment. How can I check it in cron job? On stripe documentation it is giving js code. I cant use javascript in cron i need this in php i.e (laravel).

I get this link but it is in javascript.

[Stripe Link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status)

Comment: what are you using cron job for? when you create a subscription for a product on a customer, stripe charges that customer on a recurring basis. you don't have to make any extra request

Comment: created a cron job to get payment every month. What happens if that payment is failed?

Comment: please have a read: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview

Comment: Thanks i will look into it...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running automated jobs to create recurring payments, you should use [Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview), which are supported by Laravel and you can read about [creating subscriptions here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#creating-subscriptions).

When future [subscription invoice payments fail](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#settings), you have several options for [handling the recovery flow](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures). Laravel has some [additional documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#handling-failed-subscriptions).